# Finding the most common subarray within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Example data:

```
array(
  [[ 1.,  1.],
   [ 2.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.]])
```

with a desired result of

```
>>> [0.,0.]
```

ie) The most common pair.

Approaches that don't seem to work:

Using [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode) as numpy arrays are unhashable.

Using `scipy.stats.mode` as this returns the mode over each axis, eg) for our example it gives

```
mode=array([[ 0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with `numpy` using the `unique` function:

```
pairs, counts = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(pairs[counts.argmax()])
```

Returns: `[ 0.  0.]`

Comment: jic anyone needs to know, for .argmax() ~ "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."

Comment: Note the `axis` argument is only available in (fairly recent) `numpy` v.1.13.

Answer (score 2):

One way via the standard library is to use `collections.Counter`.

This gives you both the most common pair and the count. Use `[0]` index on `Counter.most_common()` to retrieve the highest count.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

A = np.array(
  [[ 1.,  1.],
   [ 2.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.]])

c = Counter(map(tuple, A)).most_common()[0]

# ((0.0, 0.0), 2)
```

The only complication is you need to convert to `tuple` as `Counter` only accepts hashable objects.