# How do I find the most common RGBA pixel value in a image?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have an image of a dog, which has shape `(432, 575, 4)`. The 3rd dimension in the ndarray contains the RGBA values for each pixel. I want to find out what the most common pixel is, i.e. the mode.

For a 2d array, I can use the following line: `np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)`

However, I can't work out how to only compare the vectors in the 3rd dimension of a 3d array. This question is similar, but it only works for a 2d array: [Finding the most common subarray within a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694879/finding-the-most-common-subarray-within-a-numpy-array). If I simply change the `axis` to '=1`, it doesn't give me the result that I need.

Comment: Doesn’t look like a duplicate to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't care for the image's shape, you can use `reshape` to *flatten* your image and use the linked answer:

```
rgba, counts = np.unique(a.reshape(-1,4), axis=0, return_counts=True)

# the mode here
rgba[np.argmax(counts)]
```

Comment: It works and I can now find the location of those pixels using `np.where()`

Comment: I do have a question actually. Is there a way to achieve the outcome without having to reshape the array?

Comment: @programmer1 Not that I know of. Although, overhead for reshape is minimal since it works on `a`'s data without copying.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I would prefer that as a solution, but your way works as well. It just adds in an extra step, which means more work and there could be human errors when reshaping, especially for large dimension arrays.